# 'mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found' error when passing a variable to a select query

Tags: python, mysql

I am passing a variable to my select query, but it didn't fetch any output from the table.

My code:

```
c = mydb.cursor()
value=random.randrange(1, 21, 1)
query = ("SELECT jokes FROM jokes WHERE id = %s")
values = (value,) 
str=c.execute(query,values)
mydb.commit()
print(str)
```

Error I am getting:

> mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: `str` as a variable name is bad news because `str` is a built-in. In addition, there is no need to assign a `commit()` to a variable anyway so `str=c.execute(query,values)` should just be `c.execute(query,values)` and I don't know what you expect from `print(str)`

Comment: I want the output of the query into a variable(jokes stored in the database) and pass that variable in google text to speech function.@roganjosh

Comment: But there is nothing to `.commit()` on a `SELECT`. `results = c.execute(query, values).fetchall()`, and ditch the `mydb.commit()`

Comment: @roganjosh I want id should take a value generated by a random function.value=random.randrange(1, 21, 1)
c.execute("SELECT jokes FROM jokes where id='1'")
data=c.fetchall()
for row in data:
 str=row[0]
 print(str)

Comment: This is working but I want random value in place of id=1.